# How to prevent concurrent operations from generating the same ID?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I am building an app using Node.js and MongoDB. The app generates unique ids for various requests it receives. The app checks that an id is unique by querying the database for that particular id. If an entry is found, the app generates another id and repeats the process, if not, the app uses the initial id.
An issue could appear if concurrent requests are made to the app. Two requests could receive the same id and check for duplicates at the same time. Both of them see that the id is new and proceed to use it. I am new to Node.js, MongoDB, Mongoose, and programming in general. How could I solve this issue?
**EDIT**: The ids are short and use a limited alphabet. Using Mongo's ObjectId is not an option and checking for duplicates isn't something I can just skip.

Comment: Just generate GUIDs?

Comment: Why not use the MongoDB generated `ObjectID`?

Comment: I wouldn't bother that much. Let's say you use uuid v4 which makes random values, the chances of having a repeated value is about 2^124. This is incredible low. Now checking your DB if the value exists is fine and even lowers this chance, but having the same number at the same time is almost not possible. If you aren't doing any critical banking transactions this seems negligible for me.

Comment: The ids are also returned to the user. They are very short and use a limited alphabet. I must check for duplicates, as the chance of collision is quite high.